# How to access the value of the property from DBPedia using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, dbpedia

[image]

I wanted to access ***dbt:Cricket_by_country***(value) inside of the ***dbp:wikiPageUsesTemplates*** (Property), but I am not able to access it. I am very new to the SPARQL

Below is my code

```
PREFIX cia: <http://www.semanticweb.org/neelc/ontologies/countries#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dbpedia-populated-place: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace/>
PREFIX dbcat:<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category>
select distinct ?name , ?sizeOfTeam, ?equipment, ?TeamCountry, ?Country
where
{
?cricket dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Cricket>.
?cricket dbp:name ?name.
?cricket dbo:teamSize ?sizeOfTeam.
?cricket dbo:equipment ?equipment.
?cricket dbp:wikiPageUsesTemplate ?TeamCountry .
?cricket dbp:TeamCountry.dbt:Cricket_by_country ?Country
FILTER (LANG(?name)="en")
FILTER regex(str(?cricket), "/resource/Cricket")
}
```

Comment: First thing worth noting, SPARQL doesn't put commas between `SELECT` variables, though Virtuoso (powering DBpedia) accepts them. Next, it's helpful to provide a link to one of the entities whose description you're expecting your query to return. `dbp:TeamCountry.dbt:Cricket_by_country` is definitely invalid as a property identifier; the correct identifier is one of the things that may be revealed by looking at one of the entities you expect to be described...

Comment: what is that `dbp:TeamCountry.dbt:Cricket_by_country` notation? SPARQL does not have a not a JSON like path access, where did you see this syntax?

Comment: also why `FILTER regex(str(?cricket), "/resource/Cricket")`? I doubt that each team contains this in its URI? But it also doesn't look like you want to get teams, but what are you looking for with your query?

Comment: can you please explain what your query is supposed to return in the end? This might make it easier to help you in writing the final query